# Zend GData path not working with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

All,
I'm trying to load my Zend framework with the following code:

```
require_once $themePath.'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata', 'D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient', 'D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Json', 'D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme');
```

This gets me part of the way there. However, when it tries to load Zend/Gdata/App.php on the next page it says that it can't find it. I figured that it would work but I keep getting the following error:

Warning: require_once(Zend/Gdata/App.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\Zend\Gdata.php on line 27

Line 27 is then:

```
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/App.php';
```

Why won't this work? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the path to where the `Zend` directory lives to your include path like this:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath($themePath),
        get_include_path(),
 )));
```

This way, including a file like `Zend/Class.php` will look in `$themePath` for the Zend Framework Files.  In the current situation, it can't locate the Zend files relative to where they were being included from.

Comment: Thanks Drew, is it ok if I just put this at the top of my functions.php page within Wordpress?

Comment: Yes that is fine as long as it is only run once and that you do it before you need to use the Zend files.

Comment: One more question, do I need to do something with the PATH_SEPARATOR in your code? Right now I have the following:set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath($themePath),
        get_include_path(),
  )));
 include 'Zend/Loader.php';
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Json');

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  `PATH_SEPARATOR` is just a constant that resolves to `:` on Linux, and `;` on Windows as each system uses different characters to denote path separation.

Comment: Sorry but I still get the following error: Warning: include_once(Zend\Gdata.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\Zend\Loader.php on line 146

Comment: Are all of the Zend Framework files located in `D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme`?  You need `Zend\Json.php`, `Zend\Gdata.php`, `Zend\Gdata\HttpClient.php` to be present in that folder at least.

Comment: They are all in that folder. It basically loads the Loader.php file ok but then it must drop the include file path because it doesn't find the Gdata.php even though it's there. Do I need to include your code segment at the top of each one of my Zend files?